# Remove line that appears in shape divider on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a problem using waves, they work perfectly in large resolution. But when I use the developer tool to see how it would look on mobile devices, a line appears, I would like to remove that line, but I have no idea how to do this, do I need to use media queries?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Anne's Wave</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608135822 {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            line-height: 0;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }

        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608135822 svg {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
            height: 150px;
        }

        .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608135822 .shape-fill {
            fill: #FFFFFF;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: white;
            padding: 15vh;
            text-transform: uppercase;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="position: relative; background-color: dodgerblue; min-height: 80vh;">
        <h1>BE CREATIVE!</h1>
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1608135822">
            <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
                preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path
                    d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z"
                    class="shape-fill"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Shape Divider-->
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

This is the picture of the line

[image]

Comment: Could you include a picture of the line?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Yes that would be great

Comment: I'm assuming it is an outline? If it's an outline set outline to none, but I need to see a picture

Comment: Take a look now!

Comment: unable to reproduce problem with chrome developer tools.

Comment: It is a matter of finding which HTML element is rendering the line, with your inspector tool you need to drill down and find it. After this, identify the CSS in that element. I am guessing there is a border attribute somewhere or perhaps a negative margin

Comment: Hmm, this does seem to be a problem with Google Chrome. I just tested on Internet Explorer and Safari (using my phone), and this line does not appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is just Chrome DevTools mobile view not being 100% perfect. After all, it is an emulator, not an actual mobile device. I was able to replicate this same problem on my own website, but the thin line did not appear when using an actual mobile device. Nonetheless, If you would like the Chrome DevTools mobile view to remain perfect, you could add the declaration `margin-bottom: -1px;` on your svg shape to alleviate the issue.

Comment: And you are right. Thanks for the answer!